# How to pass NSManagedObjectContext in <Window Controller with Sidebar> Application to Storyboard views?

Tags: swift, core-data, storyboard

How can I fetch  NSPersistentDocument inside Storyboard views ?.
Using: iMac, coreData, Storyboard and Swift

As long as I had only one view, the app was running fine with:

```swift
guard let document = self.view.window?.windowController?.document as? NSPersistentDocument,
      let context = document.managedObjectContext else {
    return []
}
```

... and I have the managedObjectContext by hand.

Then I switched my app to the new style of sideboards:

[image]

If I use the same code as above inside my ViewControllers (like DocumentViewController in the screenshot), it fails because document is nil.
It is probably a timing issue.. WHERE to place the code , something as viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

It would be sufficient enough if I could use a "global variable" for manageObjectContext; set under makeWindowControllers. But I all approaches failed ..

Answer (score 0):

Alright , I found a good way.

- All starts with NSDocument , makeWindowControllers(). Here, **NSManagedObjectContext** is available - no need to create NSPersistentcontainer.
- Next, pass NSManagedObjectContext in makeWindowControllers() to the ViewController's  representedObject.
- From the this ViewController, initiate all other ViewControllers and pass NSManagedObjectContext

Find more details in the image below.
[image]